# MYSQL filtering query result based on AS result

Tags: mysql, json

So i have this mysql query here :

```
SELECT
     t1.*,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM tb_pt t2
     WHERE t2.id_provinsi = t1.id_provinsi && nama_pt LIKE '%$nama%' && status_pt = 1 ) As jumlah
FROM tb_provinsi t1
WHERE status_provinsi = 0
```

the query will return this result

[image]

The problem is as you can see the query return all result whether the jumlah is 0 or not, i want to filter those result based on 'WHERE jumlah != 0' so that the query only return 1 result which the jumlah is more than 0 (id_provinsi = Prv02)

Any thoughts or idea on how to achieve this? 
Thankyou

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is that an alias in the `SELECT` clause is not yet available in the `WHERE` clause at the time the latter executes.  One way to do this is just to repeat your alias logic in the `WHERE` clause.  But, MySQL offers an overloaded `HAVING` operator which may refer to aliases:

```
SELECT
     t1.*,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM tb_pt t2
     WHERE t2.id_provinsi = t1.id_provinsi AND
           nama_pt LIKE '%$nama%' AND
           status_pt = 1) AS jumlah
FROM tb_provinsi t1
WHERE status_provinsi = 0
HAVING jumlah > 0;
```

Comment: awesome! great explanation, i didnt know mysql have 'Having' operator until now hahaha. its working now thankyou good sir. Have a nice day :)